# Need an optimized way to get the required output

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Is there an optimized way to trim the beginning and end blank spaces from the below data array field values, have used three approaches, but need a more optimized way.

Note: there might be more than 20 objects in the data array and more than 50 fields for each object. Below payload is just a sample; field values can have digits or strings or dates of any size.

```
{
"School": "XYZ High school",
"data": [
    {
        "student Name": "XYZ    ",
        "dateofAdmission": "2021-06-09     ",
        "percentage": "89   "
    },
    {
        "student Name": "ABC    ",
        "dateofAdmission": "2021-08-04     ",
        "percentage": "90   "
    },
    {
        "student Name": "PQR    ",
        "dateofAdmission": "2021-10-01     ",
        "percentage": "88   "
    }
]
```

}

Required output:

```
{
"School": "XYZ High school",
"data": [
    {
        "student Name": "XYZ",
        "dateofAdmission": "2021-06-09",
        "percentage": "89"
    },
    {
        "student Name": "ABC",
        "dateofAdmission": "2021-08-04",
        "percentage": "90"
    },
    {
        "student Name": "PQR",
        "dateofAdmission": "2021-10-01",
        "percentage": "88"
    }
]
```

}

Three approaches I've used:

First approach:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

//variable to remove beginning and end blank spaces from values in key:value pairs for data
var payload1 = payload.data map ((value , key ) ->
value mapObject (    ($$ )) : trim($)) 

---
//constructed the payload
payload - "data" ++ data: payload1 map ((item, index) -> {
    (item)
})
```

Second approach:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload - "data" ++ data: payload.data map ((value , key ) ->
value mapObject (    ($$ )) : trim($))  map ((item, index) -> {
    (item)
})
```

Third approach:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
        "Name":payload.School,
        "data": payload.data map ( $ mapObject (($$):trim($) ) )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a more optimized way? What is really the problem with your solutions?

Comment: Client says the memory management is not proper, due to variables etc

Comment: I'm sorry that is not quite clear. One should test if there are any actual issues with the different  versions. Otherwise is just an esthetic opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution using the update operator:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
        case data at .data ->
            data map ($ mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (key):trim(value) ))
}
```

Note that your first two solutions are exactly the same, and both have an unneeded map() at the end that doesn't seem to have any purposes. The third solution is very similar but uses an incorrect key name for the school name (`Name` instead of `School` as in the example). There's nothing particularly wrong with each solution other than those minor issues.